# How do I disregard traffic where the visitor has done a specific action in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

Essentially, I want all visitors that follow this specific "funnel" to be ignored in the stats:

1. Go to the website (landing: /)
2. Click on "this specific link"
3. No other action taken.

I'd prefer to have this as a separate view so that I can compare stats with and without the aforementioned users.

Is this possible with Google Analytics?

Thanks.

Comment: When the use clicks the link, do you send an "event"?   Or is there a specific page they visit afterwards?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It's not set up yet, but I'd send an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Patrik Alienus

Once a user finished your funnel you can trigger an event and then create a view with a filter, based on this event. Example:
[image]

Comment: Filters discard data as it comes in.   Doing this would prevent seeing any traffic that doesn't match the filter.      I'd recommend a "segment" instead.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller, Patrick said he wants a separate view. Creating a separate view and using segment in it just doesn't make any sense :-)

Comment: I've been so crazy busy that this task has falled so far down the list of priorities that it's no longer even on it. I will thusly set this as answered as I'm sure it will work :)